# Android Studio : its made 3 apps by one APK file on my device

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm using Android studio for making android app.

but i have a problem that when i run the app , i found 3 apps on my device ,and all of them belonging to the same APK file.

also i'm sure that the **mainfeest.xml** has one `<intent-filter>`

```
<activity
            android:name="com.amman.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but i guess the problem from **Build Veriants** , but im not sure :(
[image: Build Veriants]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what are the names of other apps? during the android studio build/gradle build there is a manifest merge which combines all the manifests in the library projects u included. I assume the 'other' apps are from them, try removing

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

from the  all lib projects manifests

Comment: remove this lines from android "user" library , right ?!?!

Comment: i did it , but the same stuation,
i removed these line from the all libs on the app

Comment: try a clean build. plus go and check the generated manifest in the build/manifests/debug folder ?

Comment: Thanks @nizammoidu
i cleaned it then debug the app , its working now :D